# Given $v \in C^n$ that $u^Hu = 1$, and $D = iuu^H$ find all eigenvalues of $D$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given $v \in C^n$ that $u^Hu = 1$, and $D = iuu^H$ find all eigenvalues of $D$

Well, I believe that $D$ is composed of orthonormal vectors, because of $u^Hu = 1$.

Which means I believe that all eigenvalues will be $1,-1$. maybe even more likely:

eigenvalues of value $1$ will be the $rank(D)$ and the rest $n-r$ times will be eigenvalues $-1$.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Presumably those first couple words should be "Given $u\in\Bbb C^n$" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $D$ is a rank-$1$ matrix (why?) and therefore it has an eigenspace of dimension $n-1$ (why?). Therefore, if you can find one vector $x$ such that $Dx=\lambda x$ which is not in that big eigenspace, then you have found all of the eigenvalues (why?). You shouldn't have to work too hard to come up with this $x$.

(Note: Your guesses are largely correct, except that the other eigenvalues are not $-1$.)

Comment: Why $D$ is of rank n-1?

Comment: Cuz if it is true eigenvalues are 0,1 (one zero and n-1 1's)

Comment: Yes. You will be able to see why $D$ is of rank $n-1$ if you choose a vector and actually do the multiplication; it's not at all subtle.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that as soon as I wake up. Thx Eric!

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: Ah, sorry, I just noticed this: the nonzero eigenvalue should be $i$, actually, since $D$ has an $i$ in its definition.

Comment: Still coudnt prove that rank is n-1. :(

Comment: I solved it. Rank = 1.

Comment: Eigenvalues = i (one time), rest are zero